# Add layers above labels QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis-3

Update for QGIS 3.2 of previous queries raised for earlier versions 
[Symbols above labels in map QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230671/symbols-above-labels-in-map-qgis)

Labels always appear on the top label layer, as previously described.  I want to label multiple layers, but don't want every label to appear in the top layer.  I use some labels for background context, but don't want them to take priority over the main layers of maps.  I've looked at some workarounds suggested, but none are really working for me.  My best solution at the moment is to use transparency & other formatting to lessen impact of some labels.

Below is an example, where I am using place names used for context, but with the point labels removed. I can format the point labels differently and make them take preference to differentiate, but ideally I'd like these to appear under my point layer. The points are the key element of the map, not the place name and should be taking priority - both the marker and the label.

[image]

I can also tweak individually label positions to fix specific issues, but not ideal as I need to use the map at different scales and don't want to manually have to adjust for each case.

Have I missed anything in 3.2 which allows more control over labels/layers, or any other workarounds that allow better control of labels or allow other layers to appear above labels?

I am also playing around with using multiple maps in print composer, but ideally I'd like to find a way to do on one map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no easy solution at the moment.

But, as you already suggested, overlaying multiple maps in print composer is the way to go.
(also see: [Synchronizing views in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250339/synchronizing-views-in-qgis-print-composer/272607#272607))