# QGIS Layout: Putting all your maps in your layouts on one favorite location at once

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Currently I am making a project template that is meant to have a lot of map layouts. Potentialy this will lead to more than 30 maps that can be created (not all will be used) but they are focused on the same spot, 'Aka a favourite location' that can be set. Now I know you can do this manually each time for each load out. However this will take some time to it one by one especially if you have a lot of potential maps. **To save time, my question is if there is a command where I set all my map layouts to that same location at once?**

Comment: Do you prefer a GUI solution (could work by re-purposing the Atlas feature) or a PyQGIS solution?

Comment: Yeah something like that a gui solution with a prompt.

Comment: This is related but would require to put all maps in one multi-page layout https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250339/synchronizing-views-in-qgis-print-composer

Comment: Yeah nice option but that is kinda double work unless you can give me a way to put all my layouts in one multi page setup this is sadly not an option.