# Set grid position behind map in print layout QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, layouts, mapping

I have created a map in the print layout in QGIS.
Once the coordinate grids are added to the map, they overlay the current map that I actually want to show.

[image]

For me, grids are just secondary information but right now they cut through the real informative map.
I would like to position them behind the map, so they only show in the white space outside the map e.g.

[image: map2]

How can I change the position of the map to superposition, and the grid lines to supposition?

Comment: Have you tried changing the style of the grid?

Comment: Under the sub-category `Grids`? Yes, there is no such thing there where I can change the position of the grid lines relative to the map itself

Comment: You may try to create your grid as a layer, then you could place it anywhere between your layer

Comment: That was my worry too @J.R. Seems odd you cannot change the position of grid lines and map immediately in the print layout.

Comment: Not really, obviously no one has ever wanted to do it before now. I'm sure that you could contribute the necessary changes if you find it necessary. Or create a grid layer and place it wherever you like

Comment: You may also try to play with the blend mode and  line opacity of the grid you may be able to find a combination of setting that give an acceptable result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question. I have been thinking about this for the last few hours and have been playing with a workaround- here is the basics of a rough example. The concept involves using two map items in the layout. Add the first map item to the layout, and adjust the scale and extent to your liking. Create a grid for this map item and adjust the spacing, frame, draw coordinates and any other grid properties you want. Next, turn off layer/s in the main map canvas, refresh the layout and lock layers and styles for this first map. Now go back to the main canvas and turn your layer/s back on. Now head back to the layout and add a new map item on top of the first. Turn off the background on Map item 2 so essentially you have a vector layer with a transparent background sitting on top of the grid for map item 1. The only thing is you need to set the scale and extents for map item 2 so that they match map 1 exactly. I admit is it a bit fiddly to adjust frames, scales extents etc. but with some playing around you should be able to get a reasonable result. I put together the layout below fairly quickly just to show the idea:

[image]

I also recorded the short screencast below. Just for demonstration, I have unlocked layers on the first map and refreshed the layout. Here, I am turning map 2 on and off so you can see the map with transparent background sitting on top of the grid and the 2 vectors lining up.

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Its one of these answers that are obvious once you had the idea - but first you have to have the idea. Great job!

Comment: Thank you @Babel!

Comment: You could probably use data defined override to get the second map item to synchronize with the first

Comment: Thank you @BenW. I think this is the smartest workaround indeed!

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Duplication and synchronisation of the map is definitely the key to solve this issue, as @BenW already suggested. The map underneath should contain the grid afterwards.

But there's one question missing: `how can we easily synchronise "Map 1" with "Map 2"?`

For map synchronisation we can simply define an **Overview** in the grid map ("Map 2") targeting "Map 1", enable "*Center on overview*" and disable frame style  (Fill style: no brush, Stroke style: no pen). Then we have to overwrite the map scale of "Map 2" with the following expression: `map_get( item_variables( 'Map 1'),'map_scale')`

That's it, "Map 2" will follow "Map 1" immediately.

(The idea for map synchronistion was born here: [Synchronizing views in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250339/synchronizing-views-in-qgis-print-composer/272607#272607))

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the color of the grid to transparent. It will be invisible
2. Set `Frame Style` to `Exterior Ticks`: outside the map, you will have small lines.

[image]

Comment: guess you can set "Grid type" to "Frame and annotations only" instead of setting grid color to transparent.